# Deleting a multiple documents in a MongoDB collection by a nested array element

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am new to Mongo and I have a question about deleting documents using PyMongo.

I have a collection called `mycollection`. It has documents looking like this:

```
{
    "field1":"value1",
    "field2":"value2",
    "array_field": [
        "id1",
        "id2
    ]
}
```

I want to delete all documents in the collection which has `id1` in the `array_field`.

How can I do this? (I am using PyMongo, I would appreciate examples based on it :) )

Comment: I don't know the python driver, but in the shell you would do it with simply `db.collection.deleteMany("array_field": "id1")`. You just have to adapt it to your specific driver. Doc : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/ and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/

Answer (score 1):

this should do

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

mydb = client["DATABASE"]
col = mydb["mycoll"]
 
query = {"array_field": "id1"}
d = col.delete_many(query)
 
print(f"{d.deleted_count} documents deleted")
```

Comment: Isn't the query `{"array_field": "id1"}` will delete only the documents where the `array_field` is `id1` (but not where it is an array containing `id1` ?)

Comment: nope https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element

Answer (score 1):

```js
   db.collection.deleteMany({
      "array_field": {
        $in: [
          "id1"
        ]
      }
    })
```

Check the mongoplayground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nkhSCRyR9K-

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/